# Set Database when worker retrieving job from database

Tags: laravel

I have two database in my Laravel 8 app. The username and password of both database is same but database name is different. So I created a middleware which set the database name based on user's email.

The problem is I have a job on database `queue_connection` but when worker tries to retrieve the job, middleware doesn't get call and worker only looks for job in default database.

How can I set database name so that worker can retrieve jobs from desired database instead of default database

**Middleware**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $auth_email = Auth::guard('api')->user()?->email;
    if ($auth_email === 'first_user@example.com') {
        config(['database.connections.fe_mysql.database' => 'Database-1']);
    } elseif ($auth_email === 'second_user@example.com') {
        config(['database.connections.fe_mysql.database' => 'Database-2']);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Laravel queue worker requesting database with default database connection and during this request `Auth::user()` is `null` because there is no access token being sent in the request.

So the question is how can I change database connection based on the logged in email. I tried storing email in `session` as follows

```
session(['adminEmail' => \request('email')]);
```

Now retrieving this email from session and setting database based on email as follows

```
$auth_email = session('adminEmail');
        if ($auth_email === 'first_user@example.com') {
            config(['database.connections.fe_mysql.database' => 'Database-1']);
        } elseif ($auth_email === 'second_user@example.com') {
            config(['database.connections.fe_mysql.database' => 'Database-2']);
        }
    
        return $next($request);
    }
```

The problem with the above code is the session value will keep on changing whenever a user logs in, so I cannot rely on session value in this way

Comment: can you include example of the queries that are failing? i would not do it the way you are suggesting.

Comment: Actually, I am not making any query, but queue worker is the one who retrives the job from database in background. How can check query made by queue worker?

Answer (score 0):

I too was stuck on this problem until I realised that the DB connection wasn't being purged

Once you set the new DB config, you need to then `purge` the connection.

`DB::purge('mysql');` is the code you are looking for

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $auth_email = Auth::guard('api')->user()?->email;
    if ($auth_email === 'first_user@example.com') {
        config(['database.connections.fe_mysql.database' => 'Database-1']);
    } elseif ($auth_email === 'second_user@example.com') {
        config(['database.connections.fe_mysql.database' => 'Database-2']);
    }

    DB::purge('mysql');

    return $next($request);
}
```

---

In addition to the above, a few questions from me which may provide a better answer to your situation

1. As you are fetching the `email` with `Auth::guard('api')->user()?->email` This is already connecting to another DB - assuming this is your intended result?
2. Confirming you've registered this middleware in the `Kernal.php`
3. How does `queue_connection` DB fit into the grand scheme of things with `Database-1` and `Database-2`

Comment: I tried DB::purge('mysql'); but that didn't work for me. As regard to your questions

1. Yes, when I use `Auth::guard('api')->user()?->email`, I get the correct email

2. Yes, I did register the middleware in the `Kernal.php`

3. `queue_connection` is not another database but a connection defined in `queue.php`. in `.env` file, I have set `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`

Comment: Can you share the `Config/Database.php` section relating to mysql? Reason is `DB::purge('mysql');` assums the connection name is `mysql` however upon closer inspection, it appears that `DB::purge('fe_mysql');` may be the way to go based on your config. 
Try `dd(config(['database.connections.fe_mysql.database')` before `purge` in my answer and see if the config is actually being updated.

Comment: Actually, after posting the question, I have removed `fe_mysql` and now there is just `mysql` connection in `database.php`. I have confirmed this by logging `config('database.connections.mysql.database')` before purge

Comment: Ok. If you dd(...) after each `config(...)` do you get the intended results when the email specified matches? If so you may need to `Cache::flush()` before running `DB::purge('mysql');`

Comment: As per log I am getting the correct config based on email. I tried `Cache::flush()` but that didn't work